# NgbModal respond very slow after using same modal again and again

Tags: angular7, ng-bootstrap

I use a modalService ie. NgbModal to submit the Form on server. This form is having like 50 to 60 fields.

When the form is submitted multiple times then after few submissions the website becomes extremely slow - like unable to type anything, dropdown does not show up etc.

The issue has only been with modals, if same form submitted on pages then this works fine.

I have tried debugging the code using Augury but I believe Augury does not show up the entryComponents

This is how the modal is open.

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddOrderComponent,this.modalOption).componentInstance;


//Closed.
activeModal.dismiss('Close click')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with one of the setting for adjusting the layout RTL to LTR. A function was executing again and again. I managed to resolve this with the help of Chrome JavaScript Runner tool